# Software for visualizing very large graphs

Tags: graphviz, graph-visualization, large-data

I have a very large (about 205k edges and 200k nodes) graph of text nodes (names) that I would like to visualize using something like Graphviz.

The problem with running this on Graphviz (using sfdp) is that if I turn off overlapping (which is necessary in order to produce a readable graph) sfdp runs out of memory.

Is there any other tool like Graphviz that would manage to convert a graph of this size into an image of nonoverlapping nodes?

Comment: 200k text nodes - you'll need to zoom in quite a bit before you'll be able to read anything. I'm wondering what you'll be doing with such a graph - pre-processing the data and therefore reducing the number of nodes and edges isn't an option ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it with such large data sets, but you could give [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) a try. There is a plugin called [noverlap](https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/noverlap/) that prevents nodes from overlapping.