# Visualize large graph with Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a dataset in the form of node1, node2 and want to use networks to build a graph. It is fairly a large dataset  which leads to a graph with 500k nodes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

df = pd.read_csv('large.csv')
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'node1','node2')
```

This part code runs very quickly which converts datafram into a graph. Then I tried to apply spring layout:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
```

This part of the code takes forever. If I try different layout like circular_layout or shell_layout it would be very quick but the layout is fir with my graph.

Is there a better way to apply spring_layout for such a large graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that large graphs I would not recommend to use `networkx` for visualisation of such large graphs. Alternatives are `graphviz` or `Gephi`.
Take a look at the following list of related questions:

- [Huge Graph Visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368317/huge-graph-visualization)
- [Visualize big graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667166/visualize-big-graphs)
- [Visualizing Undirected Graph That's Too Large for GraphViz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238724/visualizing-undirected-graph-thats-too-large-for-graphviz#comment102544_238724)
- [Software for visualizing very large graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459466/software-for-visualizing-very-large-graphs)
- [How to visualize large graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909097/how-to-visualize-large-graph)

Comment: some links are not working, can you please update the links of questions, Thankyou!